# mysql select sum of count group by weekdays

Tags: mysql

Mysql query I have following tables

Company table:-

```
id company_name company_createddate
1  ABC           2015-01-01 12:45:23
2  LMN           2015-01-11 09:45:23
3  PQR           2015-02-16 23:45:23
```

User table:-

```
id username
1  John
2  Mary
```

Order table:-

```
id company_id user_id order_name  order_createddate
1  1          1       Sales       2015-02-16 09:45:23
2  1          1       Sales3      2015-02-20 09:45:23
3  1          1       Marketing   2015-02-24 09:45:23
4  2          1       Sales2      2015-02-17 09:45:23
5  1          2       M1          2015-02-16 09:45:23
6  2          2       M2          2015-02-23 09:45:23
7  2          2       P1          2015-02-26 09:45:23
```

Output required:-

```
Week day          user name     Pipeline Orders
16 Feb - 22 Feb   John          2 (ABC), 1(LMN)
23 Feb - 01 Mar   John          3 (ABC), 1(LMN)
16 Feb - 22 Feb   Mary          1 (ABC)
23 Feb - 01 Mar   Mary          1 (ABC), 2(LMN)
```

Week days is order_createddate
In 16Feb-22Feb Week, 2 orders created for company ABC
And in 23Feb-01Mar Week, 1 order created for company ABC, I want to show total number of order generated till 01 Mar Week, So i need output of 3.

Please help!

Comment: What would the output be if Mary had some orders too?

Comment: @eggyal, yes I want to show the records for all the users and companies. Output required updated...

Comment: Okay.  Whilst it is possible to create this exact output purely using SQL, some elements (namely the formatting of the "Week day" column; and the concatenated grouping within the "Pipeline Orders" column) are much more suited to being performed in the presentation layer of your application code.  Since MySQL does not have native support for analytic functions, the aggregation of the "pipeline orders" is also easier to perform in the data access layer than in the RDBMS itself.  Do you really need the SQL resultset to be *exactly* as shown?

Comment: I have attempt this. Not getting output required, please check      "SELECT concat(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orders.order_createddate, INTERVAL(0-WEEKDAY(orders.order_createddate)) DAY),'%d-%b'), ' - ', DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(orders.order_createddate, INTERVAL(6-WEEKDAY(orders.order_createddate)) DAY),'%d-%b')) as weekd, 
users.username as uname, concat(count(orders.id),' (',companies.company_name,')') 
FROM `orders` 
LEFT JOIN companies ON (orders.company_id = companies.id)
LEFT JOIN users on (orders.user_id = users.id)
group by orders.company_id, orders.user_id, week(orders.`order_createddate`)"

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(STR_TO_DATE(concat('2015 ',wk,' 1'), '%Y %u %w'), ' to ',
STR_TO_DATE(concat('2015 ',wk,' 0'), '%Y %u %w')),
User.username, GROUP_CONCAT(som) from (
select DATE_FORMAT(order_createddate,'%u') wk,user_id,
concat(Company.company_name ,'(',CONVERT(count(1),CHAR),')') som from `Order`
join Company on `Order`.company_id = Company.id
group by wk,user_id,company_name ) t 
join User on t.user_id = User.id
group by wk, User.username
```

the time limit should be in sub select clause t.

if you dont like the week format, change them by modify the first line's date format

sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9c21/2)

Comment: @Aruti use sql fiddle tested and it works well, click the url i give from the answer to see it yourself

Comment: @amow I have check the sql fiddle. I think required of aruti is that " Count total no times companies come form initial to week format" . i.e between 2015-02-23 to 2015-03-01 company ABC comes 1 time but here requirement is 3